# How to retain ControlBox UI feel when ControlBox is set to false in COmpact Framework (win mobile)

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

My forms need to remove the 'x' - (the "smart minimize" - which in fact is not so smart) and the 'OK' button on a few forms.  Unfortunately when I do that the little keyboard input icon moves from the middle to the right hand side and the lower bar turns grey instead of black.

I would like to just be able to remove the minimize and OK controls (or just override their handlers) - but unfortunately I am unable to do that in CF.  (what a mistake, MS!)

Is there a way to put back some of the UI look and feel (like the black bar)?

Like I said, Ideally we would like to either change the text "OK" to some other word or just overload the user initiated minimize (clicking the X or the ok).

(I will try to put up some screen shots when I can to show what I am talking about)

EDIT

Note also that I have added two items to the main menu in the form initialization.

```
    // create three menu items to go at bottom of form/on main menu
    // add new menu items to main menu
    // get rid of 'X' (smart minimize) and OK controls

    menuNext = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
    ...

    mainMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuPrevious);             
    mainMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuNext);
    mainMenu.MenuItems.Add(menuCancel); 

    MinimizeBox = false;                        
    ControlBox = false;
```

NOTE
I generate the forms and items programmatically - not with the form designer.  This is a requirement since these forms are made on the fly based on configuration files at run time.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this using the emulator. I set ControlBox and MinimizeBox to false and it worked as expected.

Comment: @yms  - note that I also added some menu items to the main menu.  I think that also has something to do with it.  But things look fine unless I remove the OK button/ControlBox

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue even if I add menus. However I did notice that if you do the same on the desginer the generated code will always do all these operations between a call to SuspendLayout() and a call to ResumeLayout(false). Maybe you could try doing the same...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the designer.  These forms are generated programmatically.

Comment: I meant to try using SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout(false) programmatically...

Answer (score 1):

Tim, here are some `P/Invoke` calls I found helpful to show & hide the `HHTaskBar` and the `MS_SIPBUTTON`:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowW", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowCE(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

public enum WindowPosition {
  SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,
  SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040
}
```

Here is the wrapper I wrote for it:

```
static IntPtr _taskBar;
static IntPtr _sipButton;
static void ShowWindowsMenu(bool enable) {
  try {
    if (enable) {
      if (_taskBar != IntPtr.Zero) {
        SetWindowPos(_taskBar, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 240, 26, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_SHOWWINDOW); // display the start bar
      }
    } else {
      _taskBar = FindWindowCE("HHTaskBar", null); // Find the handle to the Start Bar
      if (_taskBar != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_taskBar, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_HIDEWINDOW); // Hide the start bar
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception err) {
    // log my Error (enable ? "Show Start" : "Hide Start", err);
  }
  try {
    if (enable) {
      if (_sipButton != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_sipButton, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 240, 26, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_SHOWWINDOW); // display the start bar
      }
    } else {
      _sipButton = FindWindowCE("MS_SIPBUTTON", "MS_SIPBUTTON");
      if (_sipButton != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_sipButton, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_HIDEWINDOW); // Hide the start bar
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception err) {
    // log my Error Wrapper(enable ? "Show SIP" : "Hide SIP", err);
  }
}
```

And finally, here is how I use it:

```
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[MTAThread]
static void Main() {
  ShowWindowsMenu(false);
  try {
    Application.Run(new Form());
  } catch (Exception err) {
    // Log my error
  } finally {
    ShowWindowsMenu(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't keep the control box look and feel.  My take here is that he *wants* to keep the caption bar and Windows icon, he simply wants to completely remove the (ok) or (X) button or override their behavior.

Comment: Perhaps there is some string reference to the (ok) or (X) button (like `HHTaskBar` and `MS_SIPBUTTON`). If he stumbles upon those during his quest, he can modify my `ShowWindowsMenu` to show and hide those.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem and struggled to find an answer until I stumbled upon the following url http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158579.aspx

It mentioned a style called WS_NONAVDONEBUTTON that seemed applicable to this problem but this code was for C++.

It looks like somebody has already written a wrapper for it and this solved all my problems.

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid55A69F22A80DB21F0DB8F0F3EAA3F7D17849142C.aspx?s=button#L8

For your information I used the HideXButton method in the OnActivated override of my base form and suddenly the X and Ok are no longer visible.

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern UInt32 SetWindowLong(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    int nIndex,
    UInt32 dwNewLong);

[DllImport("coredll.dll")]
public static extern UInt32 GetWindowLong(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    int nIndex);

public const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
public const UInt32 WS_NONAVDONEBUTTON = 0x00010000;

public static void HideXButton(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    UInt32 dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);

    if ((dwStyle & WS_NONAVDONEBUTTON) == 0)
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle | WS_NONAVDONEBUTTON);
}
```